# jQuery get previous month from php

Tags: php, jquery

I have made this script that get's the month and the year from calendar.php and I would like when I click the link previous month to get the previous month but also when month number reach 1 make the year - 1. How can I do something like that?

```
<html>
<head></head>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
get_data();
});

function get_data(a, b) {

$.get('calendar.php', { 
    month: a, year: b
    }, 

    function(response) {
    $el = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'data').html(response);
    $('#datas').prepend($el);
    height = $el.height()+'px';
    $el.css({'opacity': 0, 'display': 'block', 'height': '0px'}).animate({height: height }, 500, function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    })
});
}
   </script>
<style>
#datas {
overflow: hidden;
}
.data {
display: none;
}
</style>
<body>
 <a href="#" OnClick="get_data(9, 2012);" > Previous month</a>
<div id="datas">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you are dealing with Maya calendars, there is plenty of js libraries that will prevent you for making a server call for such a simple task.

Comment: could you give me an example of library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'calendar.php',
    success: function(data) {
        // Parse your data and do all neccessery refreshing
    }
});
```

in order get yerstaday you can use

```
var d = new Date(/* data that you get from calendar.php*/);
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
```